# Сдвиг меню при обновлении страницы

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Иногда слетают ярлыки меню при обновлении страницы. Вчера было замечено 2 раза.

2 разных компа, на одном браузер *Firefox 53.0.3 (32-бит)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m — не воспроизводится ни при приклеенной, ни при отклеенной панели навигации.

Comment: Какие отступы (`margin`, `padding`) для съехавшей части показывает Firebug?

Comment: Firefox 53.0.3 (32-бит), Windows 10 не воспроизводится.

Comment: Ничего подобного не замечал. Пользуюсь в основном FF. Расширений никаких не установлено, которые могут влиять на страницу?

Comment: @insolor, посмотрел, точно такая же версия браузера

Comment: @alexolut, нет, расширений нет

Comment: @Arhad, не могу сказать, сразу не догадался посмотреть